# Axios Post Request Sending Undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, axios, api-design

I am having an issue with sending data from an Axios post request to my ExpressJS post route.  When I try to read the data sent on the post route it shows as undefined.  This is my Axios post:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:3000/temps/heating', {
    messageType: 'heating',
    toggle: 'on'
}).then(res => {
    console.log(res);
}).catch(e => {
    console.log(e)
})
```

and this is my ExpressJS Post route below.  I have tried to use `req.params` `req.body` & `req.messageType`

```
routes.post('/heating', (req, res, next) => {
    const messageType = req.data;
    console.log(messageType);
})
```

I thought that because Axios is sending "data" I request data on the NodeJS post route?

Thanks

Comment: you can try to print 'req' and see what you get there. you should have req.messageType

Comment: Does your Express app use `body-parser` or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your express app make sure to use `body-parser`: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

In your route you should then be able to access `req.body.messageType`:

```
routes.post('/heating', (req, res, next) => {
    const messageType = req.body.messageType;
    console.log(messageType);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using express.js in your node app. If that's the case, it would be `const messageType = req.body.messageType`;

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying.  I tried that but get a TypeErrror: Cannot read property 'messageType' of undefined.  Any advice?

Comment: You need to add body-parser in nodejs+ expressjs for extract json data in nodejs and get value using  req.body.messageType.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser